# Inner join with if condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I was trying to write a query with inner join only if RepID of Table1 exists in Table2, if not do not join table2. With the query that i used below, i do not get from both the tables if repID doesnot exist in Table2. How is it possible? I am using sql server 2005. Thank you in advance!

```
Select * from Table1
inner join Table2 on Table1.RepID = Table2.RepID
where Table1.Date = @Date
order by Table1.Date desc
```

Comment: Do you mean if repID is NULL?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Table1` should be obvious that nothing from `Table2` will be in the result, which begs the question: why do you think you want to join to `Table2` at all? Suggestion: write two queries, one for each condition (`RepID` exists in both tables, `RepID` exists only in `Table1`), then `UNION` them together, if necessary providing DBA-approved default values for any missing values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An inner join will only return a row if matches are found in both sides of the join. If you're looking for something that will return all rows from Table1 but only records from Table2 when a match is found, you want a left outer join:

```
select * from Table1 as t1
left outer join Table2 as t2
    on t1.RepID = t2.RepID
where t1.Date = @Date
order by t1.Date desc
```

Comment: Thanks Justin! Very good explanation. I am sure i wouldn't forget this again!

Comment: Your query will return all rows from `Table1`, no rows from `Table2`, and if more than one match is found on the 'right' side then the row on the `left` side will be duplicated. Please explain to me how such a query is useful.

Comment: @onedaywhen  I dont have more than one row on both the tables with a RepID. Is there something that i m still missing, please let me know. :-)

Comment: @Ram: well then, the joins doing nothing at all (other than overhead)! What do you think the join is doing?

Answer (score 2):

Try "LEFT JOIN" instead of "INNER JOIN".

The word "LEFT" means "Always include every record from the table on the LEFT of the join," in this case Table1, since you will write:  Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2, and "Table1" is on the left of that pair!  :-)

Comment: I dint know, Thanks for the help! :-)

Comment: Can you guess what a RIGHT JOIN does?  ;-) ;-) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like what you actually want is a left outer join, isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
    FROM Table1
        LEFT JOIN Table2 
            ON Table1.RepID = Table2.RepID
    WHERE Table1.Date = @Date
    ORDER BY Table1.Date DESC;
```

Comment: Your query will return duplicate rows from `Table1` if there is more than one matching row in the 'outer' table. You could fix that by adding `DISTINCT` to the `SELECT` clause but better still just remove the join entirely. Which leaves me wondering, what is the point of this answer?

Answer (score 0):

That's what outer joins are for.

```
Select * from Table1
left outer join Table2 on Table1.RepID = Table2.RepID
where Table1.Date = @Date
order by Table1.Date desc
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up on outer joins!