# INNER JOIN with Data Exits Condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, query-optimization

I am writing query to fetch data from two table, Products and ProductsImages.
my query is:

```
    SELECT p.*, pi.*
    FROM ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId, ProductPrice 
    ORDER BY ProductId) AS row_number FROM Products ) p
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() 
     OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId, ImageId,ImagePath  
    ORDER BY ImageId) AS row_number FROM ProductsImages ) pi 
    ON  p.ProductId = pi.ProductId
    AND p.row_number = pi.row_number
    Where p.ProductId='131';
```

I have to write a condition for running INNER JOIN that is: **Implement INNER JOIN if ProductsImages has images of giving productId *else it should run without join*. and show just products detail except images.** this query is not showing the product detail like name and price if productsImages dont have any image.
***Restriction: I have to implement only INNER JOIN.***
kindly help me out and guide me how can i implement if-exits condition in this case. thanx

Comment: [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402922/inner-join-with-if-condition?rq=1) is not upto my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such case why don't you write `left join,`

Left join keeps all the records from product table even for non matched records with image table

```
 SELECT p.*, pi.*
    FROM ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId, ProductPrice 
    ORDER BY ProductId) AS row_number FROM Products ) p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() 
     OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId, ImageId,ImagePath  
    ORDER BY ImageId) AS row_number FROM ProductsImages ) pi 
    ON  p.ProductId = pi.ProductId
    AND p.row_number = pi.row_number
    Where p.ProductId='131';
```

Comment: my task/assignment/requirment is to go with inner     join only.. edited in problem description too..

Comment: Back to Left Join. **Probably its only solution with less CPU cost.** Thnx for help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the inner query way. Example:

```
SELECT p.*, ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() 
OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId, ImageId,ImagePath  
ORDER BY ImageId) AS row_number FROM ProductsImages pi WHERE p.ProductId = pi.ProductId AND p.row_number = pi.row_number )
FROM ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId, ProductPrice 
ORDER BY ProductId) AS row_number FROM Products ) p
Where p.ProductId='131';
```

There is no join in this. :(

Comment: Thanx for help. I am back to left join because it is giving error **"Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."**

Comment: If you can attach the code in Sql Fiddle then possibly, i can correct the query. It's hard to write perfect query, when tables are not there. ;)